# How to solve this ODE? How to evaluate this integral?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following ODE?
$$ \frac{ \mathrm{d} x(t) }{ \mathrm{d} t} = \alpha x(t) \left( 1 - 
\frac{ x(t) }{ \beta + \frac{ \gamma }{ 1 + \mathrm{e}^{- \gamma (t - \lambda) }}  } \right),$$ where $x = x(t)$ is the unknown function, whereas $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\lambda$ are constants.

My Attempt:

> We can write the given ODE as 
>   $$ -\frac{1}{x^2} x^\prime + \frac{\alpha}{x} = \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta + \frac{ \gamma }{ 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma(t-\lambda) }}  }. $$
>   Or, 
>   $$ \frac{ \mathrm{d} }{ \mathrm{d} t} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) + \frac{\alpha}{x} = \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta + \frac{ \gamma }{ 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma(t-\lambda) }}  }. $$
>   Multiplying both sides of the last ODE by $\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t}$, we get 
>   $$ \frac{ \mathrm{d} }{ \mathrm{d} t} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} + \frac{\alpha \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t}}{x} = \frac{ \alpha \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} }{ \beta + \frac{ \gamma }{ 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma(t-\lambda) }}  }, $$
>   which can be written as 
>   $$ \frac{ \mathrm{d} }{ \mathrm{d} t} \left( \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} }{x} \right) = \frac{ \alpha \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} }{ \beta + \frac{ \gamma }{ 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma(t-\lambda) }}  }, $$
>   and so 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} }{x} &= \int \ \left(  \frac{ \alpha \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} }{ \beta + \frac{ \gamma }{ 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma(t-\lambda) }}  } \right) \ \mathrm{d} t. \\
> &= \alpha \int \ \left( \frac{ \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} }{ \beta + \frac{\gamma \mathrm{e}^{\gamma(t-\lambda)}}{ \mathrm{e}^{\gamma(t-\lambda)} +1  } } \right) \ \mathrm{d} t \\
> &= \alpha \int \ \left( \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} \left( \mathrm{e}^{\gamma(t-\lambda) } + 1 \right) }{\beta \left( \mathrm{e}^{\gamma(t-\lambda) } + 1 \right) + \gamma \mathrm{e}^{\gamma(t-\lambda) } } \right) \ \mathrm{d} t \\
> &= \alpha  \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma \lambda} \int \ \left( \frac{ \mathrm{e}^{ (\alpha+\gamma)t } + \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} }{ (\beta + \gamma)  \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma \lambda} \mathrm{e}^{\gamma t} + \beta } \right) \ \mathrm{d} t \\
> &= 
> \end{align} $$

What next?

Is what I've done so far correct? If so, then can we analytically evaluate the integral? I'm afraid I can't think of any trick that will work for sure.

Comment: I would simplify the integral firstly.

Comment: the result leads to a hypergeometric series

Comment: @unseen_rider can you please take time having a look at my post now? I've just edited it, simplifying the integral, as per your advice.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thank you so much for your comment. I would be really grateful if you could please write out a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

The result cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. It involves a special function (see below) : the Gauss hypergeometric function.

Since the first parameter is $1$, it could be equally expressed with the Incomplete Beta function.

In case of some particular values of $\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}$ the special function might be reduced to a simpler function.

[image]